# Suppose you choose 5 cards from a standard 52 card deck

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many different choices of cards are possible if all $5$ cards must be diamonds?

Comment: Hello, I assume this is your first time on this website so welcome :)! I would like you to put in some of your working out, as it will help to get an answer from the other members, and is good practice overall to show that you have made effort. ps I would of down voted if this was not your first post.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Assume instead you have a $13$ card deck that are all distinct diamond cards. (Assuming order matters) How many ways are there to choose the first card? The second? The third?

Comment: If we should choose 5 cards out of 13 and take into consideration the order the answer can be : 13x12x11x10x9 @User99185

Comment: Yes. And if order doesn't matter, do you know what the answer would be then? (I just realized that this is probably the correct interpretation of the question)

Comment: In that case we wil divide 5! Yeas?

Comment: Yes.  The second is usually shown as ${13 \choos 5}$, though there are many other notations.